# eclipse shortcut(keys) to create a package under a project src/main/java?

Tags: eclipse

I am bored using the mouse for creating a package in an eclipse java project. Is there a shortcut for this. 
Please share. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no such short-cut available as of now.Check yourself by typing ctrl+shift+L to see the list of all shortcuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General`(from left list)->`keys`(under the General) -> write "package" in the textbox and all the shortcuts about package's management should appear.

Answer (score 1):

Click on 'src' folder press Ctrl + N, type package on the wizard then press enter and provide package name to create a package under src folder on Window

Comment: When you say Click, mouse enters the picture :)

Answer (score 0):

For mac:

```
Command + Alt + N
```

For windows:

```
Ctrl + Alt + N
```

This command would give you a list of options so that you could create project, class or package.

However, this command does not create the package under `src/main/java`, and there's no command to do that for you unless you write your own Eclispe plugin. In fact, packages are not always under `src/main/java` (e.g., see here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.1/ide#eclipse), so there's no reason for Eclispe development team to implement that feature.

Answer (score 0):

create your own short key via Window -> Preferences -> key, then search for new package, define a short key for it, remember to set "on windows" select box, if you are running on windows.